# Constructing credible interval for store opening times

Tags: r, bayesian, credible-interval

**Overview**: Suppose I have a log which records the time at which customers visit a store. For the sake of this example, say I have 10 stores in the dataset.

Example data for Store 1:

1. Customer 828: 9:34 am
2. Customer 383: 10:34 am
3. Customer 154: 4:45 pm
4. etc..

I'd like to construct a, say, 95% credible interval for the opening time.

**Ideas**: In vague terms, I have though that it should be possible to formulate this in Bayesian terms. Namely, I could start with some prior that the start time is 540 minutes from 12am (i.e., 9am) and update that belief based on the data [EDIT: see comment below].

The problem is that I am unsure how to formulate this technically. It would be trivial if I were trying to estimate the true mean visit time. Here however, I am using data that is inherently one-sided (in reality, a person cannot visit a store before it opens) and trying to construct a (two-sided) credible interval about the point.

---

EDIT: it occurs to me that this problem could be thought of in terms of quantiles. That is, one where the goal is to estimate, say, the 1st and 99th percentile of a population from a sample.

Ex: estimating the shortest person (opening time) and tallest person (closing time) in a population from a sample.

Comment: Your prior should be a distribution not a point and should reach back to the earliest possible time.  You may also think that 9.00 is a more likely opening time than 8.59 or 9.01.

Comment: @Henry Yes, of course. What I was trying to say was a distribution with some parameter set to 540 (e.g., a normal with mean=540).